# How to configure Spring Security to use OAuth instead of Basic Authorization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I'm building a REST Application using Spring Security OAuth. Until now I can make a requets to get an access token

```
curl http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -d "username=user&password=pass&client_id=client&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password"
```

And getting a successful response

```
{"access_token":"b9590e0c-dc2c-4578-9246-ab46ab626b2c","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"56b73a2c-9993-4bbe-90db-58d207aeb3f1","expires_in":3599,"scope":"read"}
```

But when use the access token to request a secured resource I'm getting redirected to login page bacause of Spring Security Configuration.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Spring Security OAuth2 Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    protected static final String RESOURCE_ID = "oauthdemo";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/resources/**").and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("ROLE_USER")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
        }

    }
}
```

Request secured resource

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer b9590e0c-dc2c-4578-9246-ab46ab626b2c" -v http://localhost:8080/resources/demo

* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fec92003000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fec92003000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /resources/demo HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer b9590e0c-dc2c-4578-9246-ab46ab626b2c
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AD13E5504E72BDFED23E4C253A584D68; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://localhost:8080/login
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 23 Jul 2014 17:23:12 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I tyr to change Spring Security Configuration to:

```
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
    //super.configure(http);
}
```

But instead of redirect to `/login`page I'm getting `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`.

And yet worst if I add user credentials whitout Authorization headers and access_token, I can access to secured resources.

```
curl http://user:pass@localhost:8080/resources/demo && echo

WELCOME TO /demo!!
```

Is there something in spring configuration that I'm doing wrong?

This is the whole proyect: https://github.com/gee0292/OAuth2Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in the security configuration.

The error is that I'm register only the autorization server in createRootContext.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    ...

    private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(CoreConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, OAuth2ServerConfig.OAuth2Config.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        return rootContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

In `rootContext.register(...)` I'm registering OAuth2ServerConfig.OAuth2Config.class instead of OAuth2ServerConfig.class, causing that only the authorization server works.

Another way to do it

```
private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    //rootContext.register(CoreConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class, OAuth2ServerConfig.class, MethodSecurityConfig.class);
    //rootContext.refresh();

    rootContext.scan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(this.getClass()));

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

    return rootContext;
}
```

because all the configuration classes are in the same package.